# Can I use GimBal for developing mobile application using HTML5 or phoneGap

Tags: html, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

in one of our client project it is recommended that we need to use GimBal (https://www.gimbal.com) for GeoFencing and contextual notifications.

On first walkthru, we find that GimBal provides SDK for iOS and Android separately,

so just wondering if anyone has used GimBal to develop non-native application (hybrid) applications, if yes than can we have brief steps .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Gimbal in native language. Gimbal has written in C and ported android and iOS. You can use it Gimbal framework for updating data, adding new place and getting results. After  Gimbal finish it's job, you can parse it in UIWebView in iOS or Android webview. It's call hybrid architecture.